# How to get value of just created Realm entry?

Tags: swift, realm

i'm creating realm entry with this code and it works fine.

```
        let new = Exercises()
        new.name = new_name
        new.notes = new_notes

        try! RealmDB.write({ () -> Void in
            self.selectedDate.exercises.append(new)
        })
```

as soon as the entry is created in realm database i need to update several uitextfields with values of that entry.

```
NameField.text = String(XXXXX.name)
NotesField.text = String(XXXXX.notes)
```

i just can't find the right piece of code for that XXXXX. please let me know if you have some ideas.

simplified realm structure looks like this.

```
    Dates {
        date {
            type = date;
            objectClassName = (null);
            indexed = NO;
            isPrimary = NO;
            optional = NO;
        }
        exercises {
            type = array;
            objectClassName = Exercises;
            indexed = NO;
            isPrimary = NO;
            optional = NO;
        }
    }
    Exercises {
        date {
            type = date;
            objectClassName = (null);
            indexed = NO;
            isPrimary = NO;
            optional = NO;
        }
        name {
            type = string;
            objectClassName = (null);
            indexed = NO;
            isPrimary = NO;
            optional = NO;
        }
        notes {
            type = string;
            objectClassName = (null);
            indexed = NO;
            isPrimary = NO;
            optional = NO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `self.selectedDate` object is in the same scope as your `UITextField` objets, it should simply be a matter of:

```
let latestNote? = self.selectedDate.exercises.last
NameField.text = latestNote.name
NotesField.text = latestNote.notes
```

If that isn't the case, then the easiest course of action would be to perform a query with Realm to re-fetch that data you just saved.

If you haven't got a way to properly differentiate `Dates` entries in your database, it might be worth adding a primary key field.

```
class Dates : Object {
   dynamic var uuid = NSUUID.UUIDString

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "uuid"
   }
}
```

That way, you can hang onto the primary key value of the object you want to display, and simply query Realm for it like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let dates? = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Dates.self, key: "<UUID>")
```

Let me know if you need any clarification/follow-up!

Comment: thank you so much!! you made my day! self.selectedDate.exercises.last did the job for me.

Comment: Oh! Awesome! My pleasure! All the best of luck! :)